# NDK HelloWorld project : How to create .h files using javah

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am trying to create a helloWorld app which will print a log..

- i tried compiling the project using ndk
- created .so file in libs folder

**Problem:**
 - i dont know how to create machine generated header files according to my HelloWorld.java class
 - Is it because of that its giving me the Error

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found
```

My Android.mk file looks like

```
 LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)  
include $(CLEAR_VARS)  
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog  
LOCAL_MODULE    := ndk1  
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hello.c  
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Answer (score 2):

For Android Studio projects the command reads like this:

```
cd C:\<path to your app>\src\main\java

javah -o ../jni/NameOfHeaderFile.h package.name.of.java.class.YourJavaClass
```

In words: Navigate to the "java" directory of your app. One level above this directory should be your jni folder where the header file should go. Give your header file a name with the -o parameter. Tell javah what Java class you wanna use to create the header file with the seconds parameter. This java class must be identified by its full package name.