# Qt for Android JNI: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, android, qt, java-native-interface

I am trying to get a String array from Java and use it in my Qt Android C++ (and ultimately in my QML code) but I get the following runtime error (i.e. a crash):

```
W System.err: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no static method 
"Lcom/test/myTest/JniTest;.getSSIDList(V)[Ljava/lang/String;"
```

The Java code is as follows:

```
package com.test.myTest;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class JniTest
{
    public static int fibonacci(int n)
    {
        if(n<0)
            return -1;
        else if(n==0 || n==1)
            return n;

        return fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2);
    }

    public static String[] getSSIDList()
    {
        List<String> ssidList = new ArrayList<String>();
        ssidList.add("string 1");
        ssidList.add("string 2");

        String[] strings = new String[ssidList.size()];
        strings = ssidList.toArray(strings);//now strings is the resulting array

        return strings;
    }
}
```

The C++ code is:

```
void AndroidInterface::test()
{    
    //qDebug() << fibonacci(4); //this works
    qDebug() << getSSIDList();  //this crashes with the error above
}

int AndroidInterface::fibonacci(int n)
{
    return QAndroidJniObject::callStaticMethod<jint>("com/test/myTest/JniTest"
                                                 , "fibonacci"
                                                 , "(I)I"
                                                 , n);
}

QStringList AndroidInterface::getSSIDList()
{
    QAndroidJniObject stringArray = QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod("com/test/myTest/JniTest"
                                                 , "getSSIDList"
                                                 , "(V)[Ljava/lang/String;");

    jobjectArray objectArray = stringArray.object<jobjectArray>();

    QAndroidJniEnvironment qjniEnv;
    const int n = qjniEnv->GetArrayLength(objectArray);

    qDebug() << "Got jobjectArray of length:" << n; // correct

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        qDebug() << "Iteration:" << i;

        jobject element = qjniEnv->GetObjectArrayElement(objectArray, i);

        qDebug() << "Got jobject of type:" << qjniEnv->GetObjectClass(element);

        // ...

        qjniEnv->DeleteLocalRef(element);
    }

    QStringList list;
    return list;
}
```

The current implementation of the `getSSIDList()` has just a test dummy body.

I have a button in QML that invokes the `AndroidInterface::test()` code above, which works for the `fibonacci()` method, but crashes for the `getSSIDList()` method with the error above.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Apparently, I got the signature wrong:

    QAndroidJniObject stringArray = QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod("com/test/myTest/JniTest"
                                                 , "getSSIDList"
                                                 , "(V)[Ljava/lang/String;");

should be without the `V` in `(V)`...

    QAndroidJniObject stringArray = QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod("com/test/myTest/JniTest"
                                                 , "getSSIDList"
                                                 , "()[Ljava/lang/String;");

Comment: Can someone put this question to answered? I am not allowed to answer any questions because "Some of my previous answers were not well received" due to a critical repIy I once posted on tthe Math forum...

Comment: Maybe the wise move would be to delete the question. I believe that the error you found in your own code does not have a significant value for the community.

Comment: I think my problem could still be relevant. Reading the Qt doc it was not at all clear that I shouldn't have added the V in the empty argument list, and that's why I first tried with (V). Of course, it wouldn't be relevant to a specialist like you, but to beginner's like me, it would. Thanks for your nice comment anyway.

Comment: I can close the question as duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/24007688/192373 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/31063912/192373, but *close as duplicate* is considered rude these days. The bottom line, you should always [run `javah`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37296501/192373) to generate correct signatures for your native methods.

Comment: Hi Alex. Good catch, finding those duplicates! Maybe one reason I couldn't find those is that the title doesn't mention the java.lang.NoSuchMethodError error, which is the first thing I searched for, and which other people might search for in the future, if they get the same error. I know you don't need the reputation credits, given that you have so many already, but why don't you answer this question, and put it to solved? I'll gladly give you the credits, since you were the only one to react...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you did not provide the correct JNI signature for the native method. We don't need **`V`** in `(V)[Ljava/lang/String;`, but we need it in `([Ljava/lang/String;)V`.

It is possible, but tricky to construct correct C/C++ signatures for naive methods by hand, but luckily, you don't need to do that.

Android Studio, for one, will assist you on that.

If you don't have this built into your IDE, use **javah** utility to extract a header from your Java classes. This works even if you actually use *Kotlin* or some other JVM-compatible language.

Note that the **javah** tool is planned to be removed in the next major JDK release. The tool has been superseded by the `'-h'` option added to **javac** in JDK 8.